# I want to build user journy toure in react js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, progressive-web-apps

I want to build user journey for react multiple pages application  when user create an account on web app first time which library can i use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-timeline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-timeline/) of material UI. This is a nice library for creating a timeline interface, it provides the following customisation on the interface out-of-the-box

- Position of the content of each event - *left, right, alternate, etc.*
- Specify the colour of the dot or circle denoting each event separately
- Provides minimal customise over the dot
- Specify the content or icon inside the timeline dot, [here is the example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-timeline/#customization)

Other than the above, more customisations can be done by overriding the styles.

Moreover, the material UI's documentation is very easy to read and understand, for every example, there is a Codesandbox & StackBlitz link, sample code, etc.

Comment: No, react timelie is differnt things, i want to develop like this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-journey  but this library is onely for single page web app , i my  web app  have tab and  route  i want to apply this journey on this